# How do i display content from a MySQL DB in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

OK, the title may be misleading, I'm a complete novice in MySQL queries via PHP

What im actually trying to do is display a specific title of a row in a link.. for instance:

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"$path{$row['url']}\">Link Name</a>"; ?>
```

`url` being the row which holds the name of the link eg, `link-one`. So the finished link would output 
(if you were to view source):

```
<a href="path/to/the/link-one">Link name</a>
```

My question is how do i select a certain entry in the `url` row? not just the next/previous/random entry. This may be easy but i cant find an answer. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean other than `SELECT * FROM table WHERE url='path/to/the/link-one'`?  You'll have to provide more details of what your table looks like, and by which criteria you want to select the row.

Comment: that great but it would require me to make a new query, am i right? my current query is.. `SELECT url,fn FROM $dbtable ORDER BY 'order' ASC` i need to find a peice of data in the `url` column called `link-one`

Comment: Official links for [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/training/) and [PHP: MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) are the best place to start learning with a plenty of examples and descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do the trick?

```
SELECT url,fn FROM $dbtable WHERE url LIKE '%link-one' ORDER BY order ASC
```

Comment: i think i havent explained clearly. this: `$row['url']` is there a way of modifying this little snippet so it displays a specific entry in `url` say `$row['url=>4']` 4 being the fourth entry in that row.. ?

Comment: would this work like this for a variable? : `$query = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select ...;` also can a sql query in php be called anything other than query and sql?

Answer (score 0):

For this you would do something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo '<a href="'.$row["link"].'">'.$row["name"].'</a>';
```

Though php isn't as useful if you don't have a db back end I recommend reading through W3School's sql tutorials, they are quiet good (and free) http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/default.asp

Comment: wouldnt this return just the first result in the row? i have a row or rather column called `url` which has around 30 entries. i need a certain one to displayed in the actual href/link/url

Comment: That is where the `where` clause comes in.  With it, the query will return the first row that whose id matches the variable $id  @Wh1T3h4Ck5 That is sql based around php, you're mis informed

Comment: I find the official source to be a list of commands, whereas mine is a nice guided tutorial, teaching you not only the keywords/syntax but also how to actually use it.  Why not agree to disagree and have both links on the post/comments?

Comment: guys both your links will help me understand the basics and hopefully improve my terrible MySQL skills. lets not argue :P